# Understanding returning values functions C

Tags: c, arrays, function, char

I'm trying to understand how the return value of a function works, through the following program that has been given to me,

It goes like this :

- Write a function that given an array of character v and its dim, return the capital letter that more often is followed by its next letter in the alphabetical order.

And the example goes like : if I have the string "B T M N M P S T M N" the function will return M (because two times is followed by N).

I thought the following thing to create the function:

I'm gonna consider the character inserted into the array like integer thank to the ASCII code so I'm gonna create an int function that returns an integer but I'm going to print like a char; that what I was hoping to do,

And I think I did, because with the string BTMNMPSTMN the function prints M, but for example with the string 'ABDPE' the function returns P; that's not what I wanted, because should return 'A'.

I think I'm misunderstanding something in my code or into the returning value of the functions.

Any help would be appreciated,

The code goes like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int maxvolte(char a[],int DIM) {    
    int trovato;
    for(int j=0;j<DIM-1;j++) {
        if (a[j]- a[j+1]==-1) {
            trovato=a[j];
        }   
    }
    return trovato;
}

int main()
{
    int dim;
    scanf("%d",&dim);
    char v[dim];
    scanf("%s",v);
    printf("%c",maxvolte(v,dim));
    return 0;
}
```

P.S

I was unable to insert the value of the array using in a for `scanf("%c,&v[i])` or getchar() because the program stops almost immediately due to the intepretation of '\n' a character, so I tried with strings, the result was achieved but I'd like to understand or at least have an example on how to store an array of character properly.

Any help or tip would be appreciated.

Comment: If you are using `scanf` you need to allocate `dim+1` bytes for the array to leave room for the string terminator char `\0`.

Comment: This `if (a[j]- a[j+1]==-1);` in fact does nothing. Mind the trailing `;`. I recommend to learn using a debugger to trace your code.

Comment: Also for the sake of readability, please intend your code properly.

Comment: Why didn't you set default to `trovato`?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp: "*If you are using scanf  you need to allocate dim+1 bytes*" not only when using `scanf`.

Comment: Some example input you show with blanks between the letters other you do not. Is this by intention?

Comment: @alk - hehe. Intend or Indent?! :p

Comment: "*with the string 'ABDPE'*" in C "strings" have to be quoted by double.quotes. Single quotes are use for *single* characters only.

Comment: @alk The assignment is to use an array of chars with a given dimension - not precisely a c-string. The input could be gotten without the '\0'.

Comment: @enhzflep: Nice catch ... :}

Comment: @JohnnyMopp: Ah well, yes. Fair enough. But still, the OP talks about "strings".

Comment: @alk Intention i'm sorry

Comment: @alk Yes the ';' wasn't there

Comment: Please be aware, that if for example you enter 42 as `dim` and then enter `BTMNMPSTMN` as string, most of `v` stays uninitliased, so `maxvolte` would compare garbage by reading uninitialised memory and with this as well invoke the infamous Undefined Behaviour. So the function may very well return garbage if not crashing or doing other strange stuff.

Comment: @alk Sorry i think i didn't described this properly,if the dim I'm choosing is let's say 7, i have to initialize a char v[7], so no space are initialize,that's why i asked how to store an array of character with scanf and getchar, because I could do something I'm not totally aware of with 'strings'. That's why i'd like to insert the character one by one but it results almost impossible to me due to the '\n' considered as a character.

Comment: Look at the 1st comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53031158/understanding-returning-values-functions-c#comment92962969_53031158

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182669/discussion-between-jacopoburelli-and-alk).

Comment: @alk Thanks! I think it's working,i only have to figure out a way to keep count of repetition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things, I think you did not get it right.
First you need to consider that there are multiple pairs of characters satisfying `a[j] - a[j+1] == -1`
.
Second you assume any input will generate a valid answer. That could be no such pair at all, for example, `ACE` as input.

Here is my fix based on your code and it does not address the second issue but you can take it as a starting point.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
int maxvolte(char a[],int DIM) {
    int count[26] = {0};

    for(int j=0;j<DIM-1;j++) {
        if (a[j] - a[j+1]==-1) {
            int index = a[j] - 'A'; // assume all input are valid, namely only A..Z letters are allowed
            ++count[index];
        }
    }

    int max = -1;
    int index = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; ++i) {
        if (count[i] > max) {
            max = count[i];
            index = i;
        }
    }

    assert (max != -1);
    return index + 'A';
}

int main()
{
    int dim;
    scanf("%d",&dim);
    char v[dim];
    scanf("%s",v);
    printf("answer is %c\n",maxvolte(v,dim));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int maxvolte(char a[],int DIM) { 
    int hold;
    int freq;
    int max =0 ;
    int result;
    int i,j;

    for(int j=0; j<DIM; j++) {

       hold = a[j]; 
       freq = 0;

       if(a[j]-a[j+1] == -1) {
           freq++;
       }

       for(i=j+1; i<DIM-1; i++) {       //search another couple
           if(hold==a[i]) {
              if(a[i]-a[i+1] == -1) {
                freq++;
              }
           }
       }

       if(freq>max) {       
            result = hold;
            max=freq;
       }       
}
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    char v[] = "ABDPE";
    int dim = sizeof(v) / sizeof(v[0]);
    printf("\nresult : %c", maxvolte(v,dim));
    return 0;
}
```